# Faster way to do conditional slicing on a Pandas dataframe containing a column of array

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, filter

Let's take this dataframe that has a column of arrays:

```
In:  df = pd.DataFrame([['one', np.array([1,2,3,4])], 
                        ['two', np.array([1,3])], 
                        ['three', np.array([0,2,4])]],
                       columns=['id', 'items'])

Out:
      id         items
0    one  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1    two        [1, 3]
2  three     [0, 2, 4]
```

If I want to filter by an element being in 'items' I would do:

```
In: df[ df['items'].apply(lambda x: 2 in x)] 

Out:
       id         items
 1    one  [1, 2, 3, 4]
 2  three     [0, 2, 4]
```

However, this method is extremely slow and my dataframe is very large. Is there any faster way to iterate through the elements in 'items'?

Comment: Original (but slow) solution found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858072/pandas-dataframe-selection-by-element-in-array)

Comment: I would explode `items` and use `groupby().transform()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sets` you can check if a given number (`2` here) is a `set.subset` the lists:

```
df[df['items'].agg({2}.issubset)]

     id         items
0    one  [1, 2, 3, 4]
2  three     [0, 2, 4]
```

---

Timings on a large dataframe:

```
df_large = pd.concat([df]*100_000, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df_large[df_large['items'].agg({2}.issubset)]
# 355 ms ± 3.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit  pd.DataFrame(df_large['items'].tolist()).isin([2]).any(1)
# 564 ms ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df_large[df_large['items'].explode().eq(2).any(level=0)]
# 658 ms ± 6.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Sure @anky , slightly better :)

Comment: hmm no idea tbh, working for me on version `'1.0.0'` @anky

Comment: I get: " unhashable type: 'set' " . Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does `pd.__version__` give you @redguy ?

Comment: @yatu version: '1.0.1'

Comment: hmmm looks like its the version of python. Not working in another environment with same pandas version but python 3.7.4 instead of 3.8.1 @red . Seems to work on the newest

Comment: Works in python 3.8.1. And it is also faster, 6.5 sec compared to 17 sec. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (*new in pandas 0.25.0*) with [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
df[df['items'].explode().eq(2).any(level=0)]
```

---

```
      id         items
0    one  [1, 2, 3, 4]
2  three     [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually a bit slower.

Comment: Yes. Got 20.5 sec compared to 16 sec on a random value search on my actual dataframe.

Comment: Tried it in python 3.8.1 and it is indeed faster, 10.6 sec compared to 17.3 sec

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
m = pd.DataFrame(df['items'].tolist()).isin([2]).any(1)
Out[70]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
df1 = df[m].copy()
```

And we can try

```
[2 in x for x in df['items']]
Out[81]: [True, False, True]
```

Comment: Thanks, but.. "Unable to allocate 54.5 GiB... " :)

Comment: @redguy how about using for loop

Comment: How do I create the mask in a for loop?

Comment: `df[[2 in x for x in df['items']]] `@redguy

Comment: Thanks, but it's just as fast as the old method. 17.5 sec